# Autofit columns inside JQGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid with following config

**shrinkToFit: true,

autowidth: true,**

I have not set any width to any of the columns in grid.
If I set column width manually, on large screen it does not display properly.
I want the columnns to fit automatically inside the grid **with no scrollbars**.

Is there any other way to handle this?

Comment: Which version of jqGrid is used? Please let us know with code how you achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You might have given scrollOffset: true.Set **scrollOffset:0**, Now your grid will display without scrollbars.

Comment: This does not work.. Grid columns shrinks if I use this